# How to remove the axis constraint after scaling all objects to zero on one axis?

Tags: scale, axis

I inadvertently scaled all 3D objects within a layer to zero on the Y axis. Geometry is now constrained to the X Z plane in edit mode. I basically did a S Y 0 at some point during a tonne of 2D work within that layer in X Z orthographic view so I didn't notice the error.

Geometry will move in the Y direction in object mode, but not in edit mode. Removing doubles does nothing even though there are layers collapsed on one another.

Any ideas?

Comment: In object mode, Ctrl+A then 'scale', to apply scale so that it comes back to 1, 1, 1 (that will keep the geometry as it is but you'll be able to move along y). The opposite can be "Alt+S" to clear scale (and your objects will come back to their initial scale state)

Comment: That worked thank you! Just need to clear a heap of doubles now. Alt+S would of been perfect if I had applied scale to all objects initially. I'll learn.